# What is the best view layer for Spring 3?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jsf, spring-mvc

I'm investigating presentation layers to be used with spring in our new project. I'm coming from PHP+Prado and want to move to something what is as simple as Prado and more powerfull than PHP.

I like Spring 3 and Spring MVC. It's very simple to learn and start working with. But I'm looking for "view framework" better than simple jsp. I need simple components as Datagrids, Lists, Trees drag-and-drop supported. I've created SpringMVC+Spring Web Flow 2 + Spring Faces + JSF configuration but it's very complicated to create simple things there. I need something simpler.

Do You have any ideas ?

Comment: For those who are interested - the winner is Vaadin

Comment: I know this is an old post, but can you elaborate on why it won out over the others?

Comment: It won mostly because there is no need of HTML and CSS knowledge and you can build rich, desktop-like interface in Java just like in Swing. It was perfectly meeting our needs.

Comment: Vaadin website needs fixing, lots of server errors at present.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Java EE there are currently only 2 view technologies: JSP and [Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html). JSP is old and about to retire. Facelets is newer and better and designed with JSF in mind so that they both fits smoothly in each other.

But Spring MVC and JSF are in fact competitors. They both have roughly the same goals and purposes. You should use the one or the other and not mix up them. Mixing two or more MVC frameworks in one page ain't going to work flawlessly. You can however use Spring as DI and/or Security framework in combination with JSF as MVC framework. Spring offers much more than only MVC.

Components like Datagrids, Lists, Trees drag-and-drop supported are not all available in the *basic* [JSF Component implementation](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/h/tld-summary.html). For that you'll need a component library such as [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org).

#### See also

- [Why Facelets is preferred over JSP as the view definition language from JSF2.0 onwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092161/why-facelets-is-preferred-over-jsp-as-the-view-definition-language-from-jsf2-0-o)
- [Using JSF as view technology of Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744910/using-jsf-as-view-technology-of-spring-mvc)
- [JSF implementations and component libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167509/jsf-implementations-and-component-libraries).

Comment: Is it possible to create an application with Facelets in front and Spring behing without all Spring Web Flow magic ?

Comment: I don't do Spring, so I can't answer that reliability in detail.

Comment: The descission is : JSF over Spring 3 without Spring MVC and Spring Web Flow.
Now the question is : RichfAces or Icefaces or ...

Answer (score 4):

I've used Jboss Seam + Richfaces for the last 3 years and find them both useful, but if I were you I'd also check out the [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org). It has [Spring support](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0.1/spring) and combined with [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos) or [ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com/) you would get a very simple but highly effective environment. Certainly one reminiscent of developing in PHP from a speed point of view.

Answer (score 3):

If you want those sort of rich controls, then some kind of JSF framework is the way to go. The standard JSF framework is rather poorly designed and inelegant, though.

You should have a look at [JBoss Seam](http://www.jboss.com/products/seam/) as an alternative. It's a top-to-bottom web framework that uses EJB3 and JSF, and it's pretty well integrated, making JSF a lot easier than it would otherwise be.

It's not Spring-based, though, so if your heart is set on Spring, then you need to look at other JSF implementations such as [RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces).

Spring WebFlow probably isn't necessary for you at all, so I;d ignore that unless you have a good reason.

Comment: I've already finished large application based on Jboss Seam. It's a great, powerfull framework - true. But this time I need something much simpler, without the whole EJB container etc...

But I agree that JBoss Seam looks to be the best Enterprise framework now.

Comment: Vanilla JSF just don't ship with sort of CSS skins. All it does is rendering plain HTML which you yet have to style with CSS yourself. That doesn't make it ugly.

Comment: @BalusC: I meant ugly in the framework sense, rather than the cosmetic sense.

Comment: Ah yes, makes sense now. Seam is in that opinion indeed awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Jboss [Seam](http://seamframework.org) offers all that you want. It works with Spring, but provides lot of inbuilt features by itself.

Comment: JBoss Seam uses JSF as a view layer

Comment: I guess it is not relevant anymore! From Seam site, "Active development of Seam 3 has been halted by Red Hat. Many projects have moved over to Apache DeltaSpike , and others have been absorbed into different projects."

Answer (score 1):

A very powerful and light-weight MVC action based framework is [Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/), give it a try!

Comment: I'm looking more like RichFaces

Comment: ok that's a aompletely different story.

Stripes (as Spring MVC) is action based, while JSF is component based.

Also consider switching from Spring to JBoss Seam/Weld if you use JSF.

If you choose an action based framework, imo Stripes is the best out there.

If you prefer component based framework, i especially like Primefaces (http://www.primefaces.org/) and Openfaces (http://www.openfaces.org/#1) libraries.

Comment: Also consider switching from Spring to JBoss Seam / Weld if you plan to use JSF, since they have a much tighter integration.

Answer (score 1):

Angular or GWT could also be an alternative with proper usage.

Answer (score 1):

As you are coming from PHP, JSP is probably a more suitable view technology than JSF

If you have to use Spring, use Spring 4 (not 3)

Checkout Spring Boot for more rapid development etc..

If you are developing a web application, and SEO isn't important, I would personally go down the Single Page Root with a Javascript Framework + Restful web services. I notice you mention Spring WebFlow + Components. My opinion is these are too heavyweight

If SEO is important, then checkout the Play Framework (I prefer Scala version) with SSP (Scala Server Pages).