# Advice for a UI migration from Oracle Forms to JSP

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, projects-and-solutions, oracleforms

I'm starting a new project and would like some advice.

The purpose is to migrate the front-end of a web application developed with Oracle in the back-end (version 9) and Oracle Forms 6.0 in the front-end to JSP.

The layout must be the same and it's going to be developed also Web Services in the future.

What advices and/or recommendations do you have for me?

Is there any free FW that allows to rapidly rebuild in simple JSP that look and feel of Oracle Forms? Or do you build it from scratch?

Thanks in advance for your answers and time.

Regards.

Comment: Is your expertise in Oracle Forms or Java?

Comment: Hi APC...my expertise is in Java. Beyond JSP I've worked with ColdFusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a component based MVC framework and a visual editor.

As far as I know there's only [IceFaces](http://icefaces.org) which offers [visual editor plugins](http://www.icefaces.org/main/downloads/os-downloads.iface) for several IDE's like [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org) and [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org). IceFaces is a JSF component library. JSF is a component based MVC framework. Noted should be that JSF is actually a completely new learning curve which you should really follow before touching the visual editor, else it'll be a pain to maintain all that autogenerated code.

#### See also:

- [What are differences between JSP/Servlet and JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp/2097732#2097732)
- [JSF implementations and component libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167509/jsf-implementations-and-component-libraries/2168764#2168764)
- [JSF and Facelets, getting started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855555/jsf-facelets-getting-started/1855602#1855602)
- [Netbeans IceFaces visual editor tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/icefaces-netbeans-crud-apps.html)
- [MyEclipse IceFaces visual editor tutorial](http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/icefaces/)