# Primefaces Style Doens't work correctly

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I started a JSF project and included primefaces. But I have problems with the style. It doesn't look that nice than in the official showcase. But I have no idea why.

That's what I did so far:

1. I downloaded a style and extracted it into my project.
2. I added `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/flick/skin.css" />` to my facelets template
3. I extended my web.xml with the following:

`<context-param>

    <param-name>primefaces.skin</param-name>

    <param-value>none</param-value>

</context-param>`

Unfortunately it loks like that:

[image]

fyi: That's a prime panel and a prime button :-/

can you pls help me :-)
cheers

---

Update:

Whatsoever I change in context-param. it doesn't work!

Do you need more information to help me solve that problem?

Thank you for help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched from myfaces to mojarra and now it works -.-

Comment: Why does it solve your concrete problem? You gave up and used a different framework rather than fixing the problem and continuing with this great idea.

Comment: I haven't touched JSF and Java for about over a year now. All I remember is that both libraries implement the same framework standards. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530746/mojarra-or-myfaces-jsf2-0-starter

Answer (score 1):

That's becuase you used `none` skin.

Look [in Prime different skins](http://www.primefaces.org/themes.html) to choose the right skin.

For example, if you would like `Eggplant` add:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>primefaces.skin</param-name>
<param-value>Eggplant</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: How do I know the pram-value? I tried a lot of combinations. But I don't get it working :-( Damn

Comment: you have to define the param value on startup or getting from the user. if you try Eggplant - what do you get?

Comment: It makes no difference what I try to put in there.

Comment: Where should I add the <context-param> ??

Comment: @KorayTugay you need to add it in web.xml