# Any reason to use a different JSF 2.0 implementaton other than Mojarra?

Tags: jsf-2, mojarra

In the 1.x versions of JSF, one might choose to go with a different JSF implementation than Oracle's reference implementation e.g. go with MyFaces. With JSF 2.x is there any reason to go with something other than the RI?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mojarra or myfaces (jsf2.0 starter)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530746/mojarra-or-myfaces-jsf2-0-starter) By the way, Sun is taken over by Oracle since some years.

Comment: (That potential duplicate was from more than a year ago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess its more or less the same reasons for JSF2

read this...

[mojarra or myfaces (jsf2.0 starter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530746/mojarra-or-myfaces-jsf2-0-starter)

and this

[Mojarra vs. MyFaces performance](http://werpublogs.blogspot.com/2011/10/mojarra-vs-myfaces-performance.html)

There are many more articles about the myfaces vs mojarra jsf...