# PrimeFaces-- use MyFaces or Mojarra?

Tags: primefaces

It's unclear whether I should use MyFaces or Mojarra as the JSF 2.0 implementaton with PrimeFaces. Does PrimeFaces have less issues with one or the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Primefaces documentaton, Primefaces can be used with either MyFaces or Mojarra

Answer (score 6):

Primefaces is a JSF standard compliant Component Library.

Apache MyFaces, Mojarra (or) Sun JSF are all JSF standard implementations.

As to which implementation to use, you might consider some of the answers given in the question [Difference between Mojarra and MyFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530746/mojarra-or-myfaces-jsf2-0-starter)

In terms of support, by virtue of being a standards complaint Component library, Primefaces is versatile.