# Which JSF implementation to choose?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-1.2, myfaces

I have just started working on developement of a java web-app. I have to use JSF framework in its web tier. Googling around I do see number of implementations of JSF out there viz. Apache Myfaces, Jboss Primefaces etc.

Can anyone guide me please on 
Which implementation is now be called as best from the point of -
    a) Support/Documentation/tutorials
    b) Stability
    c) Future aspects of the same
    d) Compatibility with Application Servers

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530746/mojarra-or-myfaces-jsf2-0-starter and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167509/jsf-implementations-and-component-libraries/ Note: PrimeFaces is absolutely not from JBoss and it is not a JSF implementation at all either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As *implementations*, the two main implementations are `MyFaces` and `Mojarra`. `Primefaces`, `Richfaces` and many more are *component libraries*, that work on top of an implementation.

I would say that, for starters, you should first chose the application server and try to stick to the server provided implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I am planning to use jboss server. I come to know that I can use my own implementation instead of the one which jboss already ships with. So, From MyFaces & Mojarra, what would be choice parameter ?

Comment: I would say `Mojarra` (reference implementation, and JBoss seems to favour it so I expect it to be better tested).

Comment: Anyway I do not expect the difference to be significative, if there exists other reasons to chose one or the other (v.g. you work with people which is more used to one implementation or the other). The idea of being implementations of the same API is that they should be easily interchangeable.

Comment: Yeah... that said. APIs are same meaning I could easily switch between the twos.