# Equivalent tag for <tr:goButton> in JSF 2.0 Mojarra

Tags: jsf-2

There is a tag `<tr:goButton>` in trinidad for which description is as below:

> The `goButton` creates a push button that navigates directly to another location instead of delivering an action. It can be used in place of commandButton where a server-side action is not needed.

Do we've similar one in JSF 2.0 Mojarra? If not, how can we implement this?

Comment: I've answered too fast, are you using the hotkey function from tr:goButton? If yes, there is no equivalent in Mojarra, you will need a components library or custom code I think.

Answer (score 0):

To create a simple `<a href=""></a>` tag, you could use `<h:outputLink />`.

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm not going to use hotkey function. I was just thinking if I append `faces-redirect="true"` to the `outcome` coming from `<h:commndButton action="">` then it works similar to <tr:goButton>. Is that correct?

Comment: It will result as the browser will go to the page you want (in top URL) but it will to a forward on server side. You are using navigation rules I think?

Answer (score 0):

The [`<h:button>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/button.html) does exactly that.

```
<h:button value="Go to next page" outcome="nextpage" />
```

Where `nextpage` is just the (implicit) navigation outcome. In this case, it expects a `nextpage.xhtml`.

For an overview of all available JSF 2 tags, please consult the [VDL documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/).

#### See also:

- [Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton)
- [Communication in JSF2 - Implicit navigation](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitNavigation)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete question, "Mojarra" is Oracle's reference JSF 2.0 implementation. It's therefore a bit strange to explicitly ask if a tag is available in "JSF 2.0 Mojarra". It's sufficient to ask if a tag is available in "JSF 2.0". Every JSF 2.0 compliant implementation should namely have exactly the same set of tags/components. MyFaces is another one and it has also just a `<h:button>`.

#### See also:

- [JSF implementations and component libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167509/jsf-implementations-and-component-libraries)