# classnotfound exception when running jsf + richfaces project

Tags: jsf, tomcat, richfaces, classnotfoundexception

I have a project on eclipse that is using richfaces and jsf. It is tied to a server (apache tomcat 7.0). when i run i am getting a class not found error.

Here are my libraries:

```
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-discovery-0.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
cssparser-0.9.7.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
guava-14.0.1.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
myfaces-api-2.1.10.jar
myfaces-bundle-2.1.10.jar
myfaces-impl-2.1.10.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar
org.springframework.binding-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar
oro-2.0.8.jar
richfaces-components-api-4.3.1.Final.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.3.1.Final.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.3.1.Final.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.3.1.Final.jar
sac-1.3.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
tomahawk20-1.1.14.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
xmlParserAPIs-2.0.2.jar
```

I believe i should have all the libraries....

I am getting the following error:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4823)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Also. I tried recreating the project but to no avail.

Comment: Interesting. Why are you using both myfaces and richfaces?

Comment: the myfaces classes where added due to classnotfound exceptions when working with jsf

Comment: I guess you first need to resolve the issue that why myfaces is required when project is supposed ti be based on richfaces,  most probably something in web.xml.

Comment: `myfaces-bundle` bundles `myfaces-api` and `myfaces-impl` in a single file. So, essentially, you've 2 copies of MyFaces in your webapp. Get rid of the other one.

Comment: @CoolBeans: Why is that weird? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167509/jsf-implementations-and-component-libraries/2168764#2168764

Comment: You've by the way also 2 copies of JSTL in your webapp, one JAR file for JSTL 1.2 and two JAR files for JSTL 1.2.1. Get rid of the other one.

Comment: @BalusC - aah yeah that makes sense. I have always used the sun JSF impl with richfaces so I never had to include the myFaces stuff. I thought MyFaces was a similar stack as richfaces, icefaces, primefaces, etc. The "faces" word got me little confused. Thank you for clarifying it! You rock!

Comment: I removed all the extras you pointed out but the error still remains.