# Maven can't create dependecies for jsf-component archetype project in kepler

Tags: spring, maven, jsf, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.1

When I try to create a project to work with jsf+ejb+jpa by choosing org.richfaces.cdk:maven-archetype-jsf-component archetype maven has failed to build the according directory structure and dependencies. It displayed the following error:

Could not calculate build plan:
Plugin org.richfaces.cdk:maven-cdk-plugin:3.3.4.Final
or one of its dependencies could not be resolved.
Failed to read artifact descriptor for
org.richfaces.cdk:maven-cdk.plugin:jar:3.3.4.Final

I'm using Kepler SP2 (on W7 SP1) for Java EE development with Spring and Hibernate plugins. Can they be the source of problem or it's another issue.
Could someone give some advice how to solve this one.

And any suggestions for a better way to create JSF+EJB+JPA projects are welcome. I'm going to use maybe spring and spring-security for sure in the future.

Comment: As far as i know to use richfaces you need to setup a supplemental repository (richfaces) to get all needed artifacts, cause they are not all in central.

Comment: Thanks for tip. Could your suggest on your own opinion what better to choose _richfaces_ of _icefaces_?

Comment: I've also look through:
[JSF implementations and component libraries] and(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167509/jsf-implementations-and-component-libraries) 
[JBoss Richfaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces)and decided on JBoss richfaces library components

Comment: Before I'd tried to create this Project I already set up JBoss Tools for Kepler with the support of richfaces.
Can the conflicts in JBoss/Eclipse support of mayven be source of problem.