# Redeployment of changes in Facelets pages has no effect

Tags: jsf, mojarra, eclipse-luna, jboss-tools, glassfish-4.1

i can't see my text-change in the browser when i publish a simple text-change in an Facelets page of my JSF-Project (Primefaces) in Eclipse Luna (Java EE Developer-Edition).

The publish-command changes the server-state from "[Started, Republish]"  to "[Started, Synchronized]".
This command-execution is very fast, so that i can't see a temporarly entry in the Progress-View.

As a publish of a text-change in a Java-Code results in a temporarly entry in the Progress-View, I'm confused about this behavior of my Eclipse Luna installation.

Using my Eclipse Kepler-Installation, i don't have this issue.

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli)
[INFO] de.mmo:Myproject:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- javax:javaee-api:jar:7.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.el:el-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor:jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.primefaces.themes:all-themes:jar:1.0.10:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:5.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.persistence:commonj.sdo:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.omnifaces:omnifaces:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] +- fr.opensagres.xdocreport:org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- fr.opensagres.xdocreport:org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- fr.opensagres.xdocreport:fr.opensagres.xdocreport.itext.extension:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:1.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:1.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:jempbox:jar:1.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.barcode4j:barcode4j:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- avalon-framework:avalon-framework-impl:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] \- net.glxn:qrgen:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    \- com.google.zxing:javase:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO]       \- com.google.zxing:core:jar:3.0.0:compile
```

Comment: Which JSF impl? MyFaces is known to agressively cache Facelet templates when project stage is not set to Development.

Comment: I'm using primefaces 5.1; my javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE (web.xml) was already set to "Development".

Comment: PrimeFaces is not a JSF impl. It's a 3rd party component library. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167509/jsf-implementations-and-component-libraries Perhaps you're using Mojarra? You can find it in server logs.

Comment: I found this server-log-entry: Mojarra 2.2.6 ( 20140304-1537 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.6@12949)