# How can I show/hide row of table in jsf?

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I have a table like this:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And a hibernate entity:

```
private boolean isShow;

public boolean getIsShow() {
        return isShow
    }

public void setIsShow(boolean isShow) {
        this.IsShow = isShow
    }
```

This isShow variable is get from database.

My question is how can I show/hide the row of table base on isShow variable. I'm just a beginner in JSF so sorry for this dump question.

Comment: @BalusC is this work without PrimeFaces ?

Comment: I have no idea where you got PrimeFaces requirement from. Nothing in the duplicate Q&A says a single word about PrimeFaces. Have you for instance tried the answer? If so, how exactly did it fail for you in such way that you thought you'd need PrimeFaces? If not, next time do so before making assumptions :) Perhaps this is helpful in understanding what exactly "JSF" is and what exactly "PrimeFaces" is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2168764