# Can I use more than one JSF implementation in the same project?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, myfaces

Can I use more than one JSF implementation in the same project? 
Can I mix PrimeFaces with MyFaces for example?
What are implications of that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot mix JSF implementations. By the way, PrimeFaces is not a JSF implementation. MyFaces **is** a JSF implementation, just like Mojarra.

You could however mix component libraries like PrimeFaces. See for example how you can use both [BootsFaces and PrimeFaces](https://showcase.bootsfaces.net/integration/PrimeFaces.jsf), or [OmniFaces and PrimeFaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/) (OmniFaces is mainly a utility library, but has some components).

Note that you do need a JSF implementation in order to be able to use a JSF component library at all. If you are using a JavaEE server (like Payara or WildFly), the JSF implementation is already provided by the server.

See also:

- [JSF implementations and component libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167509/jsf-implementations-and-component-libraries)