# Adding/Removing PrimeFaces header CSS and JavaScript to specified pages

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My web project unfortunately has two jars, Mojarra and PrimeFaces and we cannot remove it, the project is too big legacy.
I have removed the CSS and JS belonging to PrimeFaces, by adding the following lines to faces-config.xml

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.Head</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HeadRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

But we need to add these PrimeFaces head stuff to specific pages.

page1.xhtml: must not has these PrimeFaces CSS and JS.
page2.xhtml: has to these PrimeFaces CSS and JS.

Is there any workaround here?

Comment: using primefaces v10.0

Comment: "unfortunately"? I do absolutely not understand this tone. Mojarra and PrimeFaces are not competitors. They have both their own purpose. Mojarra is a JSF impl and PrimeFaces is a JSF component library. You cannot use PrimeFaces without Mojarra. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/2167509

Comment: Yes I am confused as to your use case and why you would want a page that doesn't have the PrimeFaces CSS and JS on page1.xhtml?

Comment: sorry for not explaining it clearly. Let me explain my problem more concisely. 
Primeface adds head of all pages that scripts
<link "/javx.f.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-saga&amp;v=10.0.0"/>

Comment: <link "/javx.f.resource/primeicons/primeicons.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=10.0.0"/>
<script "/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces"/>
if(window.PrimeFaces){PrimeFaces.settings.locale = 'en_YE_#u-ca-gregory';}
I removed tags by adding renderer class to faces-config for page1. But i need also these libraries too for page2